# SQL: Select rows by group until a condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql

If given the sample table below of actions taken by users at specific timestamps:

```
id |    ts     | action
---+-----------+------
 1 | 10039000  | scroll_10
 1 | 10039002  | scroll_20
 1 | 10039004  | click
 1 | 10039006  | scroll_30
 2 | 10044000  | scroll_10
 2 | 10044002  | bounce
```

I need to be able to pull the results before the first `non-scroll` action, for each `ID`.

If there are additional `scroll actions` for each user that occur at `timestamps` after the first `non-scroll` action, they should not be pulled.

Expected output for the sample above would be:

```
id | action
---+-------
 1 | scroll_10
 1 | scroll_20
 2 | scroll_10
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT id, action
FROM user_actions
WHERE ts < (SELECT MIN(ts)
            FROM user_actions
            WHERE action NOT LIKE '%scroll%'
            )
```

Which gives me a result of:

```
id | action
---+-------
 1 | scroll_10
 1 | scroll_20
```

So that's correct for the first 'id', but I need it to then look for the next 'non-scroll' action for the next 'id' and include that in the return, which I can't seem to get it to do. Tried to 'self-join' to the same table but can't quite seem to get the syntax correct.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih This is for MySQL

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Best if you show what SQL you have tried and the returned results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp < (select min(t2.timestamp)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.id = t.id and t2.action not like 'scroll%'
                    );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was having trouble with the exact syntax for the correlated subquery, this works perfectly.