# SQL select all rows per group after a condition is met

Tags: sql, window-functions, correlated-subquery

I would like to select all rows for each group after the last time a condition is met for that group.  This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093638/sql-select-rows-by-group-until-a-condition-is-met) has an answer using correlated subqueries.

In my case I will have millions of categories and hundreds of millions/billions of rows.  **Is there a way to achieve the same results using a more performant query?**

Here is an example.  The condition is all rows (per group) after the last 0 in the conditional column.

```
category | timestamp |  condition 
--------------------------------------
   A     |     1     |     0 
   A     |     2     |     1 
   A     |     3     |     0 
   A     |     4     |     1
   A     |     5     |     1
   B     |     1     |     0 
   B     |     2     |     1
   B     |     3     |     1
```

The result I would like to achieve is

```
category | timestamp |  condition 
--------------------------------------
   A     |     4     |     1
   A     |     5     |     1
   B     |     2     |     1
   B     |     3     |     1
```

Comment: What is the condition you want to meet?

Comment: @GordonLinoff In the example its all rows AFTER the last 0.  I will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try window functions:

```
select category, timestamp, condition
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        min(condition) over(partition by category order by timestamp desc) min_cond
    from mytable t
) t
where min_cond = 1
```

The window `min()` with the `order by` clause computes the minimum value of `condition` over the current and following rows of the same `category`: we can use it as a filter to eliminate rows for which there is a more recent row with a `0`.

Compared to the correlated subquery approach, the upside of using window functions is that it reduces the number of scans needed on the table. Of course this computing also has a cost, so you'll need to assess both solutions against your sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion on performance and the ultimate recommendation that I just need to try it :) it seems like there is no silver bullet "this is the best way to do it" in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want everything after the last `0`, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when condition = 0 then timestamp end) over (partition by category) as max_timestamp_0
      from t
     ) t
where timestamp > max_timestamp_0 or
      max_timestamp_0 is null;
```

With an index on `(category, condition, timestamp)`, the correlated subquery version might also perform quite well:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp > all (select t2.timestamp
                         from t t2
                         where t2.category = t.category and
                               t2.condition = 0
                        );
```

Comment: thanks for this, if you're able can you expand on the performance implications of each approach?